# O que há de errado com essa query?

Tags: php, mysql

Possuo uma função DBUpdate que atualiza os dados no banco de dados.
Essa função cria uma query baseada no array passado como parâmetro.

Por exemplo, se eu enviar esse array (como `$visit`)

```
  'ips' => '192.168.25.1, 127.0.0.1'
  'real' => 1
  'last' => '2017-05-19 18:15:50'
  'desktop' => 10
```

Ao executar `DBExecute('clientes', $visit, 'country = pt_BR')` essa query me é retornada:

```
UPDATE ac_analytics SET ips = '192.168.25.1, 127.0.0.1', real = '1', last = '2017-05-19 18:15:50', desktop = '10' WHERE country = 'pt_BR'
```

E então recebo o erro sql:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'real = '1', last = '2017-05-19 18:15:50', desktop = '10' WHERE country = 'pt_BR'' at line 1
```

Minha função de update completa:

```
//Altera registros
function DBUpdate($table, array $data, $where = null){
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $fields[] = "{$key} = '{$value}'";
    }

    $fields = implode(', ', $fields);

    $table = DB_PREFIX.'_'.$table;
    $where = ($where) ? " WHERE {$where}" : null;

    $query = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$fields}{$where}";
    return DBExecute($query); // Função de execução de queries
}
```

Comment: @Knautiluz Exatamente o que precisava. Irei alterar o nome das tabelas... Obrigado.

Comment: Não precisa alterar o nome das tableas. Use o caractere de escape (crase). Exemplo: `ips`, `ac_analytics`, `last` e por aí vaí. É sempre bom usá-lo pois o MySQL e outros SGDB posuem muitas palavras reservadas e hora ou outra você irá se esbarrar com elas.

Answer (score 1):

Com o comentário de um usuário (que, por algum motivo, deletou o comentário) consegui detectar o problema. Minha query possuía palavras reservadas pelo MySQL, na qual me restavam 2 opções:

- Alterar o nome da tabela para um nome que não seja reservado pelo sistema. [Você pode verificar neste link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html).
- Utilizar caracteres de escape na minha query.  ` `ips` ` `= '192.168.25.1, 127.0.0.1'`

Comment: Perdão Daniel, deletei o comentário porque não estava conseguindo colocar o crase pois o stack identificava como código e tive que sair.

Comment: @Knautiluz Eu imaginei. Se quiser adicionar crase, use o ASCII `& #96 ;` e espaços. Falta um suporte melhor do Stack para esta situação haha